# How to declare Array variable in Azure Data Warehouse?

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I have a list of strings I use in a sql query similar to this:

```
select count(*) from sometable where somefield in ('val1','val2',...'valn')
```

I use this pattern in several queries in a single stored proc. I want to reuse the stored proc, changing the values in the array periodically. Using normal SQL databases, you can declare a table variable type but that is not supported in SQL Data Warehouse. You can use a temp table, but these and table variables require more editing when the values change (requiring insert statements or unions to populate the table). How can I declare an array variable?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question/answer pair from the OP, does not demonstrate how to create an array variable, and revisits old ground of how to parameterize a list for `in`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a varchar variable and use the STRING_SPLIT function in a select statement:

```
DECLARE @ids varchar(8000)
set @ids = 'Val1,Val2,...ValN'
select count(*) from sometable 
where somefield in (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@ids, ','))
```

While this works, I'm not sure how well it scales; for performance reasons, you can fall back to using a temp table - then use VSCode to edit the insert statements (Ctrl+Shift+L is your friend).